# Android Google Maps Library freezes on General Mobile Discovery

Tags: java, android, google-maps, ssl

I'm trying to add google maps library to my project. Everything perfectly running on Samsung devices or HTC devices or Sony devices and I can see the map on this devices without any problem. But the map does not shown on General Mobile Discovery and freezes after bottom left corner google icons become visible.

When I try to open my project on GM Discovery App freezes and getting this error on the console and a few minutes later App gives warning "Application not responding"

Is there anybody know why I can't use google maps library on GM Discovery?

```
12-25 16:26:36.437 5093-5093/com.my.package E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.nb.a
12-25 16:26:36.650 5093-5093/com.my.package E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.mw.a
12-25 16:26:37.350 5093-6366/com.my.package E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x606b4488 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x62deaab0 arg=0x0
12-25 16:26:37.352 5093-6366/com.my.package E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x606b4488 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
12-25 16:26:37.663 5093-6394/com.my.package A/libc: @@@ ABORTING: LIBC: ARGUMENT IS INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x64be1a48
12-25 16:26:49.647 5093-5098/com.my.package E/dalvikvm: Fatal spin-on-suspend, dumping threads
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. After long searching I have found a solution, but I dont know how it should be implemented. PLease see it : [Fatal error with google Map v2 on Android 4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851115/fatal-error-with-google-map-v2-on-android-4-2-2)

Comment: Thanks but it did not solve my problem it's a little bit different error.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line of the issue is `Fatal spin-on-suspend, dumping threads`. You can find the detailed explanation in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790471/what-exactly-causes-a-spin-on-suspend-error-in-android).

> Some devices use a [vendor-modified version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891086/understanding-android-tight-loops-spin-on-suspend-error/) of Dalvik that gets this wrong, and aborts can happen on tight loops. I wouldn't expect to see a native method at the top of the stack in this case.